# Is there a way to make a kill shooting through a tank window?

Tags: battlefield-1

Is it possible to kill a passenger or the driver of a tank shooting through a window with a scout rifle? Or I can only attack the tank in the normal way?

Comment: K bullets work against tanks, but I want to know if a clean shot through the window can reach the passengers.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are playing as the scout class, yes bullets can penetrate into the tank and kill the people inside.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can deal damage while any parts of their character body are visible. So if you are going for a clean shot just through the tank window, yes, it is quite possible to kill your opponent.